# Python - Looping through HTML Tags and using IF

Tags: python, html, string, web, beautifulsoup

I am using python to extract data from a webpage. The webpage has a reoccurring  html div tag with class = "result" which contains other data in it (such as location, organisation etc...). I am able to successfully loop through the html using beautiful soup but when I add a condition such as if a certain word ('NHS' for e.g.) exists in the segment it doesn't return anything - though I know certain segments contain it. This is the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
details = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'result'})

for detail in details:
    if 'NHS' in detail:
        print detail
```

Hope my question makes sense...

Comment: where does this `NHS` exist? Is it in the text part? Show an example of the html you are talking about.

Comment: `detail` is an instace of BS `tag` object. To check if something is present in the text try using `if 'NHS' in detail.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll` returns a list of tags, not strings. Perhaps convert them to strings?

```
s = "<p>golly</p><p>NHS</p><p>foo</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
details = soup.findAll('p')
type(details[0])    # prints: <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
```

You are looking for a string amongst tags. Better to look for a string amongst strings...

```
for detail in details:
    if 'NHS' in str(detail):
        print detail
```