# How to replace a domain in image src in python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, replace

I have following HTML string

```
<body>
    <img
        alt="Images may be two-dimensional, such as a photograph or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a statue or hologram. They may be captured by optical devices – such as cameras, mirrors, lenses, telescopes, microscopes, etc. and natural objects and phenomena, such as the human eye or water."
        height="333"
        src="https://tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka02v000001BOfL&amp;feoid=00N2v00000Rjh9i&amp;refid=0EM2v000002ijZG"
        width="500"
    />
    <br />
    Images may be two-<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional" target="_blank" title="Dimensional">dimensional</a>, such as a&nbsp;
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photograph" target="_blank" title="Photograph">photograph</a>&nbsp;or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a&nbsp;
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue" target="_blank" title="Statue">statue</a>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram" target="_blank" title="Hologram">hologram</a>.
</body>
```

I would like to change all occurrences of img src domain from tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com to globalcommunity.networks.com in Python 3.x

Note: Looking for a solution that replaces the domain only if it present in img src. It should not replace if is in regular string or iframe src.

Any help?

Comment: Parse the XML using e.g. [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/), find and the tag you want to change and set it to whatever value you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you All for your valuable inputs.

I have solved this issue by using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<body><img alt="Images may be two-dimensional, such as a photograph or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a statue or hologram. They may be captured by optical devices – such as cameras, mirrors, lenses, telescopes, microscopes, etc. and natural objects and phenomena, such as the human eye or water." height="333" src="https://tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka02v000001BOfL&amp;feoid=00N2v00000Rjh9i&amp;refid=0EM2v000002ijZG" width="500"/><br /> Images may be two-<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional" target="_blank" title="Dimensional">dimensional</a>, such as a&nbsp; <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photograph" target="_blank" title="Photograph">photograph</a>&nbsp;or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a&nbsp; <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue" target="_blank" title="Statue">statue</a>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram" target="_blank" title="Hologram">hologram</a>. </body>'
modified_data = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# Find image and change src domain
for tag in modified_data.findAll("img"): 
  tag['src'] = tag['src'].replace('https://tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/', 'https://globalcommunity.networks.com/')
print(modified_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve your situation as mentioned here:

[How to use string.replace() in python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x)

```
string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue)
```

You can use a simple `string.replace` to resolve your situation.

In your situation:

```
yourHtmlContainer = """<body><img alt="Images may be two-dimensional, such as a photograph or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a statue or hologram. They may be captured by optical devices – such as cameras, mirrors, lenses, telescopes, microscopes, etc. and natural objects and phenomena, such as the human eye or water." height="333" src="https://tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka02v000001BOfL&amp;feoid=00N2v00000Rjh9i&amp;refid=0EM2v000002ijZG" width="500"><br>Images may be two-<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional" target="_blank" title="Dimensional">dimensional</a>, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photograph" target="_blank" title="Photograph">photograph</a>&nbsp;or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue" target="_blank" title="Statue">statue</a>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram" target="_blank" title="Hologram">hologram</a>. </body>"""
print("Before replace")
print(yourHtmlContainer)


newHtml = yourHtmlContainer.replace("tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com", "globalcommunity.networks.com")
print("After replace")
print(newHtml)
```

Output:

```
Before replace
<body><img alt="Images may be two-dimensional, such as a photograph or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a statue or hologram. They may be captured by optical devices – such as cameras, mirrors, lenses, telescopes, microscopes, etc. and natural objects and phenomena, such as the human eye or water." height="333" src="https://tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka02v000001BOfL&amp;feoid=00N2v00000Rjh9i&amp;refid=0EM2v000002ijZG" width="500"><br>Images may be two-<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional" target="_blank" title="Dimensional">dimensional</a>, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photograph" target="_blank" title="Photograph">photograph</a>&nbsp;or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue" target="_blank" title="Statue">statue</a>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram" target="_blank" title="Hologram">hologram</a>. </body>
After replace
<body><img alt="Images may be two-dimensional, such as a photograph or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a statue or hologram. They may be captured by optical devices – such as cameras, mirrors, lenses, telescopes, microscopes, etc. and natural objects and phenomena, such as the human eye or water." height="333" src="https://globalcommunity.networks.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka02v000001BOfL&amp;feoid=00N2v00000Rjh9i&amp;refid=0EM2v000002ijZG" width="500"><br>Images may be two-<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional" target="_blank" title="Dimensional">dimensional</a>, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photograph" target="_blank" title="Photograph">photograph</a>&nbsp;or screen display, or three-dimensional, such as a&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue" target="_blank" title="Statue">statue</a>&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hologram" target="_blank" title="Hologram">hologram</a>. </body>
```

For more help:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp

Comment: Hi Mateus, thank you for response. your answer even replaces a regular string (or iframe src) that contains tvfcommunity-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com. I am looking for a solution to replace only if it present in img src.

Comment: Could you iterate your HTML tags? If the answer is yes, you can do some checking to see if the changed tag is an img. I can change the code if that resolves your situation.

[python-looping-through-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729045/python-looping-through-html-tags-and-using-if)

Comment: HI Mateus, may be that works. Instead of checking afterwords, if i can check and replace then it might help.